# Jasmine: Testing a function, being called from a different function using jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am having a method in a javascript file.

```
function foo() {
  setTimeout(function() {
      bar.getSomeUrl();
      },WAIT_FOR_SOMETIME);
}
```

Now the `getSomeUrl()` is implemented as below.

```
var bar = {
     getSomeUrl : function(){
         window.location.href = 'someUrl';
         return;
     },
     anotherProp : function() {
         return bar.getSomeUrl();
     }
};
```

I am trying to test that the `getSomeUrl()` method will be called when I call the `foo()` method.

I am using jasmine for testing. My jasmine test is as below:

```
describe('This tests getSomeUrl()', function() {
    it('is called when foo() is called', function(){
        spyOn(bar,'getSomeUrl').and.callFake(function(){});

        window.foo();
        expect(bar.getSomeUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
 });
```

I don't really care about testing whats happening inside the `getSomeUrl()` because I have a separate test for that.

**All I am trying to test is that when I call my foo() from somewhere the `getSomeUrl()` gets called.**

I have the following problems:

1. If I do this way, the test fails and at the end of running all tests, the browser redirects to `someUrl`. I didn't expect this to happen because, I thought since I had a spy on `bar.getSomeUrl()` and was returning a `fake method` it wouldn't actually call the `bar.getSomeUrl()` when I called `window.foo()`.
2. So I thought may be I should do it as below:

   expect(window.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();

This doesn't make sense, because I am trying to test that `bar.getSomeUrl()` is being called.

However when I did this, test fails and I get the below error:

`Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.`

I also thought it could be the `setTimeout` function that is causing the issue and changed the `foo()` function to:

```
function foo() {
    bar.getSomeUrl();
};
```

Didn't change anything

I have been working with Jasmine and Javascript only for a few days now and have a broad understanding of how things work.

Any suggestion to make this test to pass and also a pointer as to what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is not java related. Javascript is spelled in one word and has no relationship with Java.

Comment: Took care of that. Thanks.

Comment: You have a syntax error. `bar.getSomeUrl` is an object literal (with invalid syntax). It is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `bar.getSomeUrl` should be a function, not an (invalid) object

```
var bar = {
     getSomeUrl : function() {
         window.location.href = 'someUrl';
         return;
     },
     anotherProp : function() {
         return bar.getSomeUrl();
     }
};
```

---

Second, use the [Jasmine Clock](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction#section-Jasmine_Clock) when testing code with timeouts.

```
describe('This tests getSomeUrl()', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        jasmine.clock().install();
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    });

    it('is called when foo() is called', function(){
        spyOn(bar,'getSomeUrl').and.callFake(function(){});

        foo();
        expect(bar.getSomeUrl).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

        jasmine.clock().tick(WAIT_FOR_SOMETIME);    
        expect(bar.getSomeUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();    
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented `bar.getSomeUrl` as a function. It was typo while posting the question.

Comment: Tried the suggestion. Doesn't help. Still ended up redirecting to `someUrl`.

Comment: Ok, I debugged the test runner in browser and found that I was getting an exception:
`Mock clock is not installed.`
I did a rebuild of the project and tried again, and everything seems to work. Thanks @Phil. So was the test failing because of the setTimeout function call?